# Call PHP from external php file

Tags: php, html

What I am trying to do is put all of my variables in an external php file and then call them on different pages.  I am creating workflows for multiple projects, all of these projects follow the same flow but have some different information like phone numbers and fees for things.  So what I am trying to accomplish is put all of my variables in an external file so if something changes for a project I can edit the one file versus open up the 23 different workflows I have created.

This is just a sample of all the external file will have but for 31 different projects and 14 different variables for each.

```
<?php
$project_id = $_GET["project_id"];

switch ($project_id) {
case "fl":
    $title = "Florida EPC";
    $replacement_fee = "$4";
    break;
case "tx":
    $title = "Texas EPC";
    $replacement_fee = "$6";
    break;
}
?>
```

Then just a basic rundown of each workflow

```
<div id='a1' style="display:block;">
<div align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
<b>Check the CARDS tab for the PAN.</b><br /><br />

</div>
&nbsp;
 <div align="center">
<p><i>"I'm sorry to hear you have lost your card. I can cancel the Lost card for your protection."</i></p><br><br>
 <font color="red">Was the PAN issued?</font><br /><br />
<a class="button" href="javascript:switchid('a2');"><span>Yes</span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a class="button" href="javascript:switchid('a3');">No</a>
</div>
</div>

<div id='a2' style="display:none;">
<div align="center">
<p><b>Advise the client the card was previously cancelled.</b></p>
<p><i>"Your card has already been deactivated as of (date of deactivation)."</i></p>    <br><br>
<font color="red">Is the address up to date?</font><br /><br />
<a href="javascript:switchid('a4');">Yes</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;
<a href="javascript:switchid('a5');">No</a>
</div>
</div>
```

within some of the divs all i will put is `<?php echo $avariable; ?>` when the different info will be used.  I just need to beable to call the external file on each workflow and can't figure that part out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you need is the require_once statement.

More info at http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

require_once can be used at the top of all of your pages and will only include the file a single time even when includes are nested.

Comment: OR as they are required variables require_once()

Comment: agreed, require_once is better for @brock029 case

Comment: Ok so next problem is, I have tried require once and I dont think is is getting the project_id.  The way I am assigning the ID is simply when you click the link the a href has test.php?project_id=fl.  using require once i get this error ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: project_id in C:\wamp\www\workflow_test\callscripts\workflow\epc\workflowvars.php on line 2 
Call Stack 
# Time Memory Function Location 
1 0.0011 372768 {main}( ) ..\lostcard.php:0 
2 0.0027 376792 require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\workflow_test\callscripts\workflow\epc\workflowvars.php' ) ..\lostcard.php:56

Comment: I think the problem is that your using $project_id from within a function called `main`. So at the top of your `main` function put `global $project_id;`.

Comment: @OmarJackman sorry for being such a PHP newb but would i add the global part to the external file?

Comment: @OmarJackman, Never mind got it fixed.  I wasnt assigning the project_id on the links.  I had setup a different test file that did so but the official one did not.  Thansk again!

Answer (score 1):

[PHP manual: include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Example:
`include 'vars.php';`

Other possibilities:

- [include_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)
- [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)
- [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would recommend [REQUIRE_ONCE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) instead of Include as it ends up being safer.
You may want to check out [DEFINE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) as well so you can use Constants instead of variables.